# Read data from Oral B Toothbrush - Bluetooth 4.1 Low Energy

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, gatt

I am currently working on integrating my Oral B toothbrush with the enlisted smart features. The toothbrush communicates via Bluetooth with a small screen displaying lived data. It is also possible to connect a smartphone with the oral b app before or during cleaning, and to display the live values ​​there. I was already able to connect via noble (a Node.js BLE module) after pressing the Bluetooth button, to connect to the device and to read services and characteristics which also update. As soon as you start the cleaning process, the client disconnects and a connection is no longer possible during the cleaning process, but then it works again. There is an SDK and API to the toothbrush which is only for ios and android apps. https://developer.oralb.com/

Now the question for me is how to get the sdk or the display live values ​​during the cleaning process? is there an authentication or something similar behind that? Has anyone already had experience with similar devices or with BLE devices?

```
Service a0f0fff050474d5382084f72616c2d42

     a0f0fff150474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Command)
 properties read, write, notify
 value 00 | ''

     a0f0fff250474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Data)
 properties read, write
 value 00000000 | ''

     a0f0fff350474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Auth)
 properties read, write
 value 00 | ''

     a0f0fff450474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Secret)
 properties read, write
 value 00000000 | ''



Service a0f0ff0050474d5382084f72616c2d42
     a0f0ff0150474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Handle ID)
 properties read
 value 00000000 | ''

     a0f0ff0250474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Handle Type)
 properties read
 value 01 | ''

     a0f0ff0350474d5382084f72616c2d42 (User Account)
 properties read
 value 01 | ''

     a0f0ff0450474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Device State)
 properties read, notify
 value 0200 | ''

     a0f0ff0550474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Battery Level)
 properties read, notify
 value 34 | '4'

     a0f0ff0650474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Button State)
 properties read, notify
 value 00000000 | ''

     a0f0ff0750474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Brushing Mode)
 properties read, notify
 value 01 | ''

     a0f0ff0850474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Brushing Time)
 properties read, notify
 value 0000 | ''

     a0f0ff0950474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Quadrant)
 properties read, notify
 value 00 | ''

     a0f0ff0a50474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Smiley)
 properties read, notify
 value 00 | ''

     a0f0ff0b50474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Pressure Sensor)
 properties read, notify
 value 00 | ''

     a0f0ff0c50474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Cache)
 properties read, write, notify
 value  | ''



Service a0f0ff2050474d5382084f72616c2d42
     a0f0ff2150474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Status)
 properties read, write, notify
 value 8200 | ''

     a0f0ff2250474d5382084f72616c2d42 (RTC)
 properties read, write
value 8d15ac21 | '

     a0f0ff2350474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Timezone)
 properties read, write
 value a7 | '''

     a0f0ff2450474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Brushing Timer)
 properties read, write
 value 0f | ''

     a0f0ff2550474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Brushing Modes)
 properties read, write
 value 0105020403060000 | ''

    a0f0ff2650474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Quadrant Times)
 properties read, write
 value 1e001e001e001e000000000000000000 | ''

     a0f0ff2750474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Tongue Time)
 properties read, write
 value 00 | ''

     a0f0ff2850474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Pressure)
 properties read, write
 value 03 | ''

     a0f0ff2950474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Data)
 properties read
 value 4ef1a721800002010000046478801d00 | 'Nq'!dx'

     a0f0ff2a50474d5382084f72616c2d42 (Flight Mode)
 properties read, write
 value 00 | ''
```